# Laravel Nova show different label based on user level

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-5.8

I know about the laravel label method that can be used to change the name of the resource in the nav.

I can, for instance, use the below on my Group resource to display 'Group' instead of 'Groups'.

```
public static function label() {

    return 'Group';

}
```

Does anyone know how I could define the label that's shown based on something like the user level?

what I want is something that looks like this;

```
public static function label() {

    if($user->level == 'Admin') {

        return 'Groups';

    }

    else {

        return 'Group';

    }

}
```

How do I get an instance of the user that I can use inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `auth()->user()` to get the current authenticated level. So your function might look something like this:

```php
public static function label()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    if($user->level == 'Admin') {
        return 'Groups';
    } else {
        return 'Group';
    }
}
```

You should try to see if there is any case where this fails if the user is not authenticated. You might fix that with some check like this:

```php
    if(auth()->guest()) {
        return 'Group';
    }
```

Keep in mind that this will also change the title of the resource page.

Comment: Thank You. I don't know why I didn't think to use auth()->user() just like I normally would in Laravel. Works a treat. Thanks once again.